# Adding rating to a movie using Firebase and React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to create a functionality where I add the people who added rating to a movie into an object called `voters` and from there I want to get the sum of those all of those ratings divided by the length of that object as a value of `rating` property, here is how my database looks like:

[image]

The issue I came across is that I can't seem to add values or to be precise properties inside that `voters` object. I used `updateDoc` functionality from Firebase but anytime I log in with a different user and I rate the movie it overwrites the previous rating instead of adding a new property if you get what I am saying, here is my code:

```
export const rateMovie = (movieName, rating, uuid) => {
  updateDoc(doc(moviesCollectionRef, movieName), {
    voters: { [uuid]: rating },
  });
};
```

Does anyone know how to add new properties to an object inside Firebase collection without overwriting previous data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your `voters` field is a map, in which case you can [update the nested fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) with dot notation:

```
const path = "voters." + uid;
updateDoc(doc(moviesCollectionRef, movieName), { 
  [path]: rating
});
```