# updateData overwrites data in collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection (userRecipes), which *should* contain sub collection's containing individual recipes. (I save each sub collection with the recipe's name, in this instance it's cheese)

[image]

My issue is whenever I save each sub collection, it overwrites the previous recipe.(ie. if I saved another recipe, it would overwrite cheese) In a perfect world, I would like each sub collection saved without overwriting the existing collections. Can't see why updateData isn't working in this instance, unless I'm misinterpreting firebase's docs.

```
struct SaveRecipeButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var recipeClass: Recipe
   
    func saveRecipe (){
        
        //saves from object in RecipeModel to arrays
        var ingredientArr:[String:String] = [:]
        var directionArr: [String] = []
        
        //goes through both ingredients and directions
        for item in recipeClass.ingredients {
            ingredientArr[item.sizing] = item.description
        }
        for item in recipeClass.directions {
            directionArr.append(item.description)
        }
        //sets up firebase w/ recipe as subcollection
        let newRecipeInfo: [String: Any] = [
            "userRecipes": [
                recipeClass.recipeTitle: [
                    "recipeTitle": recipeClass.recipeTitle,
                    "recipePrepTime": recipeClass.recipePrepTime,
                    "createdAt": Date.now,
                    "ingredientItem": ingredientArr,
                    "directions": directionArr
                    ]
                ]
            ]

//grab current user
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
//updates data in firebase
        do {
            try FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).updateData(newRecipeInfo)
            print("successfully save to database")
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing recipe to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }){
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "pencil").resizable()
                    .frame(width:40, height:40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Button(action: {
                    saveRecipe()
                   
                }){
                    Text("Save Recipe")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width:200)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                    
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 100, bottom: 12, trailing: 100))
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(
                        Color("completeGreen")))
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `userRecipes` is a **field** in a document, not a collection. When you call `updateData` it replaces the existing value in the `userRecipes` with the values you specify.

If you want to [update a value in a nested field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), you can do so using dot notation. So:

```
FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).updateData([
  "userRecipes.Cheese.recipeTitle": "Cheesiest"
])
```

Also see this similar question for JavaScript which I gave a few hours ago: [Adding rating to a movie using Firebase and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592584/adding-rating-to-a-movie-using-firebase-and-react)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think it fully solves the issue (which is my fault if my issue wasn't better clearly explained) - so I'm not updating the actual recipe, but adding a new field. So instead of updating the info in cheese, I'm trying to create another recipe (let's say ham) and add it to user Recipes

Comment: In that case have a look at the `array-union` operation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array